# Skill points use in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does levelling up skills have any more effect than just making me level up/get perks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37252/does-levelling-up-skills-have-any-more-effect-than-just-making-me-level-up-get-p)

What's the use of skill points other than granting access to perks? Do I get more damage output when fighting with one handed weapon if my skill is high, even if I don't use perks in that tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, every point of skill gives you a little more benefit even if you do not use the perks.  For instance, every point of speech craft improves merchant prices by 1%.  Every point of destruction [lowers spell costs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35750/what-effect-does-increasing-the-magic-skills-have) etc.  Even if you don't put perks into the skills, its still highly beneficial for you to have high skills.  Not to mention it also gives you more experience for leveling.

Comment: What about blacksmithing and alchemy?

Comment: @allov, blacksmithing increases the amount you can 'improve' armor, but you cannot improve it beyond exquisite without the perks.  Alchemy boosts potion strength